# VuePress 2 Redirects

Tags: redirect, wiki, vuepress2

I am using VuePress 2 to build a wiki docs webpage for a project. Recently we did some restructuring of our wiki pages, so now some older links are broken and point to pages which do not exist anymore. These links are from websites we do not own so we are not able to modify them internally.

As a solution I wanted to add redirects through VuePress which will point the old broken URLs to the new ones on the wiki. Unfortunately I realized VuePress 2 does not have a configuration for adding redirects.

I also tried searching for plugins and the only one I found, which is [vuepress-plugin-redirect](https://vuepress-community.netlify.app/en/plugins/redirect/) is not compatible with the latest version of VuePress.

Does anyone know of a different approach or solution?

Thanks